# Исполнение JavaScript с привязкой к DOM в node js

Tags: node.js, парсер

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли запустить JS файл который отдаёт сервер с привязкой к DOM?
Интересует имитация браузера без графического интерфейса. Возможно в NPM есть какие-то пакеты которые могли бы исполнять JS файлы содержащиеся в теге  при скраппинге сайта? В конкретном случае -- сформировать XHR запрос с статистическими данными и отправить его на сервер при DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: Это как? Поясните вопрос.

Comment: phantom, nightmare, htmlparser2

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov - интересует имитация браузера без графического интерфейса. Возможно в NPM есть какие-то пакеты которые могли бы исполнять JS файлы содержащиеся в теге <script> при скраппинге сайта. В конкретном случае -- сформировать XHR запрос с статистическими данными и отправить его на сервер при DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

Весь вопрос в том, что вам требуется получить в результате выполнения JS? Все же JavaScript это клиентская технология, она выполняется только на стороне клиента и все результаты этого выполнения передает на сервер. Проще сымитировать выполнение JS-скрипта, чем прикручивать к скриптам парсинга полноценный браузер.

Как я вас правильно понял, вы хотите напрямую обращаться на сторонний сайт с AJAX-запросами? Если так, то ищете на том сайте скрипт, который обрабатывает выдачу нужных вам данных, определяете какие входные данные ему нужны для выдачи запроса, после чего обращаетесь напрямую к этому файлу в POST/GET запросе.

Но это самый простой случай. Более продвинутые сайты используют защиту, чтобы нельзя было так сразу парсить их AJAX. Например, могут быть генерируемые при каждой выдачи страницы токены, проверки на роботов и прочие штуки. Но это надо смотреть индивидуально под конкретный сайт.

В этом случае сначала запрашивается исходная страница, с нее получаются необходимые данные/проходятся проверки, после чего делается в отдельном запросе XHR-вызов.

Comment: Ломаю голову над этим вопросом почти неделю. Если что, речь идёт о Twitter-e.
Нужно имитировать AJAX вызов, в инспекторе виден как JOT. Вызываеться из init.js. Деобфускация этого файла особо картину не прояснила. Есть ли шанс исполнить его на ноде, при том что половину значений скрипт подгребает из HTML?

Comment: а так ли необходимо получать данные из web-версии twitter. у них многое можно получить через их официальный API с тем же результатом. единственное из существенного там ограничение на частоту и срок давности результатов из поиска.

Comment: @Максим Выхрист а так совет. если уж очень надо получить те данные, которые не выдает public API используйте private API. будет намного меньше мороки с парсингом данных (там они не сильно отличаются от структуры public API).

Comment: если все же хотите использовать web-платформу, то ищите какие данные передаются вместе с запросом в init.js. этот файл единый роутер через который проходит большинство ajax-запросов. в него надо как минимум передать переменные пути назначения и данные, необходимые для выдачи новой порции информации (max_id и прочее). если нужные вам данные отдаются твиттером только авторизованным пользователям, то потребуется предварительно программно авторизоваться, получить необходимые токены и уже с ними опрашивать ajax. также там стоит защита на user agent, если он будет левый, то придет пустой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этих целей [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).
`PhantomJS` это все плюшки `WebKit` из консоли с управлением на JS и поддержкой различных стандартов и технологий: `DOM`, `CSS`, `JSON`, `Canvas` и `SVG`.